# What are the gcc flags -lm -g and -o called, and what do they do?

Tags: linux

Do you know what are these symbols called and what article I should read to learn more about them? They are in this piece of code:

```
~/gomer_math/KaprekarProject/c_version/ (master) $ make kaprekarDemo
gcc  -Wall -g -c kaprekarUtils.c -lm -o kaprekarUtils.o 
gcc  -Wall -g kaprekarDemo.c kaprekarUtils.o -lm -o kaprekarDemo
```

Comment: If you are on linux run "man gcc" and search for those symbols. You won't find "-lm" but instead look for "-l ". If this guess didn't help then please be more specific.

Comment: I added some more code. Is it better now?

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect a question post to be about a specific(**single**) problem. But your question is about **3 problems** (about `-l`, `-g` and `-o` flags). Not to say that every this flag is easily googled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should make use of the man pages on a Linux system.  They tend to display most of the flags that can be supplied.

As for your specific case:

`-l` is more of a linker flag and allows the linker to find a specific library to link the project to.  In this case `-lm` tells the linker to link the math library (so you can use functions like `sin()` and such).

`-g` produces debugging information so that you can use something like `gdb` to debug your project.

`-o` lets you specify the output file name so that your executable (or object file) is not automatically named `a.out` or some other system default

`-W` tells `gcc` to show errors and warnings. `all` after `-W` tells 'gcc` to shoo all errors and warnings

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the answer, however, I will post a ***trick because Man pages are very lengthy sometimes*** and if you want to **search for a specific string** use these two approaches(saves a lot of time), this way you can search any man page:-

```
man gcc 
     then, Just press / and write what you wanna search and enter. Use n to skip to next occurrence and N for previous.
```

If you want to grep for a pattern beginning with a hyphen, use -- before the pattern you specify.

```
 man find | grep -- -type
```